# Instantiate different cache manager in each Test Class

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test, spring-cache

In my Spring-Boot Web Application project I'm using Spring Cache to implement caching. Cache can be enabled/disabled by configuration key defined in `application.yml`. I already have existing test cases where tests are written assuming there is no cache. So by default in my `integration-test` profile caching is disabled and I initialize `NoOpCacheManager` and all my tests work.

```
@Profile(value = { "default", "production", "integration-test" })
@Configuration
@EnableCaching(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
public class CacheBeanConfig extends CachingConfigurerSupport {

    @Autowired
    private CacheConfig cacheConfig;

    @Bean
    @Override
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        if (cacheConfig.isEnabled()) {
            System.out.println("****************Couchbase CacheBeanTestsConfig cache init.**********************");
            Map<String, DeclaraCouchbaseTemplate> cacheCouchTemplateMap = Maps.newHashMap();
            Map<String, Integer> cacheTtlMap = Maps.newHashMap();

            for (CacheConfig.CacheConfigParam cacheParam : cacheConfig.getCaches()) {
                try {
                    cacheCouchTemplateMap.put(cacheParam.getName(),
                        couchbaseManager.getCouchbaseTemplate(cacheParam.getName()));
                    cacheTtlMap.put(cacheParam.getName(), cacheParam.getTtl());
                } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
                    throw new FaultException("Unable to get couchbase template.");
                }
            }

            return new CouchbaseCacheManager(cacheCouchTemplateMap, cacheTtlMap, metricRegistry);
        } else {
            System.out.println("****************NoOp CacheBeanTestsConfig cache init.**********************");
            NoOpCacheManager noopCacheManager = new NoOpCacheManager();
            return noopCacheManager;
        }
    }

}
```

I also want to write tests for verification of Caching functionality. I created a `CachedControllerTest` class where all the cache specific tests are written.

Problem is when I run

```
mvn test -Dtest=CachedControllersTest -Dspring.profiles.active=integration-test
```

All the tests in `CachedControllerTest` class are failing because cache manager is initialized with `NoOpCacheManager` even though I enabled the caching in the bean function.

I tried to create a separate profile for `CachedControllerTest` and it still fails because once `cacheManager` bean is initialized it is not getting reset.

```
mvn test -Dtest=CachedControllersTest -Dspring.profiles.active=integration-test,integration-cache-test
```

Here is my CachedControllerTest class

```
@ActiveProfiles("integration-cache-test")
@DirtiesContext
public class CachedControllersTest extends AbstractRestControllerTest {

    @Configuration
    @EnableCaching(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
    @Profile("integration-cache-test")
    public static class CachedControllerTestsBeanConfig {

        @Autowired
        private CouchbaseManager couchbaseManager;

        @Autowired
        private CacheConfig cacheConfig;

        @Autowired
        private MetricRegistry metricRegistry;

        @Autowired
        GlobalApplicationConfig globalAppConfig;

        @Bean
        public CacheManager cacheManager() {
            System.out.println("**************** CachedControllerTestsBeanConfig EnabledCaching**********************");
            cacheConfig.setEnabled(true);
            if (cacheConfig.isEnabled()) {
                System.out.println("****************Couchbase CachedControllerTestsBeanConfig cache init.**********************");
                Map<String, DeclaraCouchbaseTemplate> cacheCouchTemplateMap = Maps.newHashMap();
                Map<String, Integer> cacheTtlMap = Maps.newHashMap();

                for (CacheConfig.CacheConfigParam cacheParam : cacheConfig.getCaches()) {
                    try {
                        cacheCouchTemplateMap.put(cacheParam.getName(),
                            couchbaseManager.getCouchbaseTemplate(cacheParam.getName()));
                        cacheTtlMap.put(cacheParam.getName(), cacheParam.getTtl());
                    } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
                        throw new FaultException("Unable to get couchbase template.");
                    }
                }

                return new CouchbaseCacheManager(cacheCouchTemplateMap, cacheTtlMap, metricRegistry);
            } else {
                System.out.println("****************NoOp CachedControllerTestsBeanConfig cache init.**********************");
                NoOpCacheManager noopCacheManager = new NoOpCacheManager();
                return noopCacheManager;
            }
        }

        @Bean(name = "mtlKeyGenerator")
        public KeyGenerator keyGenerator() {
            System.out.println("****************CachedControllerTestsBeanConfig mtlKeyGenerator.**********************");
            return new MultiTenantKeyGenerator(globalAppConfig.getTenantId());
        }

        @Bean(name = CacheManagementConfigUtils.CACHE_ASPECT_BEAN_NAME)
        @Role(BeanDefinition.ROLE_INFRASTRUCTURE)
        public AnnotationGroupCacheAspect cacheAspect() {
            AnnotationGroupCacheAspect cacheAspect = AnnotationGroupCacheAspect.aspectOf();
            CacheManager cacheManager = (CacheManager) StaticContextHolder.getApplicationContext().getBean("cacheManager");
            cacheAspect.setCacheManager(cacheManager);

            KeyGenerator keyGenerator = (KeyGenerator) StaticContextHolder.getApplicationContext().getBean("mtlKeyGenerator");
            cacheAspect.setKeyGenerator(keyGenerator);
            return cacheAspect;
        }
    }

    @Component
    public static class StaticContextHolder implements ApplicationContextAware {

        private static ApplicationContext appContext;

        @Override
        public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
            appContext = applicationContext;
        }

        public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
            return appContext;
        }
    }
}
```

application.yml

```
spring:
    profiles: integration-test

cache:
    enabled: false
---
spring:
    profiles: integration-cache-test

cache:
    enabled: false
```

My requirement is to reinitialize the cacheManage for each Test Class and CacheConfig is the bean which I want to modify at the runtime so that appropriate `CacheManager` can be initialized.

In isolation if I run the `CachedControllerTest` class tests they all pass because there is no other Test Class run before that which would have initialized the cacheManager to NoOpCacheManager.

Thanks in advance for any help/suggestion to make this situation work.

**Edit 1**

Based on the suggestion by Sam, Added `@ActiveProfiles`.

**Edit 2**

AbstractRestControllerTest Class Definition

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class AbstractRestControllerTest {
}
```

Comment: FYI: `AFTER_CLASS` is the default `ClassMode`. Thus there is no reason to override the default with the default. In other words, an empty `@DirtiesContext` declaration at the class level will suffice.

Comment: Are you using the `StaticContextHolder`? If so, how is it being picked up as a Spring bean -- via component scanning?

Answer (score 1):

`@Profile` has *zero* effect on a test class.

To set the *active bean definition profiles* for an integration test, you need to use `@ActiveProfiles` from the `spring-test`module.

Consult the [Context configuration with environment profiles](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-env-profiles) section of the Spring Reference Manual for details.

Also, `CachedControllerTestsBeanConfig` must be annotated with `@Configuration` *not* `@Component`.

Regards,

Sam (*author of the Spring TestContext Framework*)

Comment: Added `@ActiveProfiles("integration-cache-test")` on CachedControllerTest class. But Subsequent test classes use the cache manager initialized by `CachedControllersTest` class. `DirtiesContext` is only added on `@CachedControllersTest`. 

I was thinking other test classes which execute tests after `CachedControllersTest` will use the `NoOpCacheManager`. But they are failing because data is served from the cache and all the assertions are failing.

Comment: How is `AbstractRestControllerTest` (and any of its superclasses) configured? Does it use `@ContextConfiguration`? Does it use Spring Boot's `@SpringApplicationConfiguration`? etc.

Comment: How is `CacheBeanTestsConfig` picked up (i.e., declared) as a configuration class in the tests?

Comment: How is `CachedControllerTestsBeanConfig` picked up as a configuration class?

Comment: In case you missed my update: `CachedControllerTestsBeanConfig` must be annotated with `@Configuration`, not `@Component`.

Comment: 1. Yes AbstractRestControllerTest uses `@SpringApplicationConfiguration`
2. `CacheBeanTestsConfig` was exact duplicate of `CacheBeanConfig` in the source. I added `@Profile` on `CacheBeanConfig`. Updated the code in the post. Yes it is a decorated with `@Configuration`
3. `CachedControllerTestsBeanConfig` is a decorated with `@Configutation`

Comment: Here is the gist of partial failure Logs. https://gist.github.com/627e49fd2b1fe999270a.git . Execution sequence of test classes is 

1. Running com.declara.server.annotations.ControllerAnnotationTest
2. Running com.declara.server.cache.CachedControllersTest
3. Other Test Classes

Comment: If I add `@DirtiesContext` on `ControllerAnnotationTest` the first test class in the test run sequence. Then all the tests pass. But then you never know which one will be the 1st test class in different environment. It will call for putting `@DirtiesContext` in `AbstractControllerTest` which I want to avoid because it will slow down the execution of test cases.